# indefinite integral of $e^{\frac{-x^2}{1+x}}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I'm wondering if there's some simple form of the integral: $\int_0^X e^{\frac{-x^2}{1+x}} dx$

For context, I'm fitting to a distribution (of the velocities of local stars) as shown below and it's well approximated by $p(v) \propto e^\frac{-v^2}{1+|v|}$. AFAIK this is not a common probability distribution, but it seems a useful one, especially if the CDF can be written in simple functions.
[image: histogram of observed stars in red, and the proposed pdf in green]histogram of observed stars in red, and the proposed pdf in green

Comment: [WolframAlpha says no](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+exp%28-x%5E2%2F%281%2Bx%29%29).

Comment: Best I found was this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1641929/399263, use $t=x+1$ change to get to $e^{-(t+\frac 1t)}$ form.

Comment: After the change of variable proposed by @zwim, this integral can be written as the difference of two incomplete Bessel functions. You may find information in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2692694/348034)

Comment: @zephyr This is a gentle reminder to consider 'accepting' an answer if your question has been resolved.

Comment: thanks @sal, your answers is great and has really helped me understand the function better - but was holding off on marking it as complete because I think there's a more general answer that can be written in incomplete modified Bessel functions

Comment: @zephyr No problem. I originally didn't go down the incomplete Bessel function route because I thought (maybe incorrectly!) that it was more like relabeling the problem. For completeness, I've edited my post to include how to write your integral in terms of the incomplete Bessels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is an elementary integral, but we can find asymptotic forms.

*For small $X$*

Since $\frac{-x^2}{1+x}=1-x-\frac{1}{1+x}$, I will consider the integral

$$
I(b)=\int\limits_0^b dx \  e^{ -x-\frac{1}{1+x}}
$$

Which differs from the original by a multiplicative constant $e$, and investigate $b \to 0$. Integrating by parts

$$
I(b)=\int\limits_0^b dx \ (1+x)^2 e^{-x} \left[ \frac{d}{dx} e^{-\frac{1}{1+x}}\right] 
$$

$$
I(b)=(1+x)^2  e^{ -x-\frac{1}{1+x}} \Bigg\vert_0^b - \int\limits_0^b dx \ (1-x^2) e^{ -x-\frac{1}{1+x}}
$$

The boundary term may be readily evaluated. Within the integral on the right we recognize $I(b)$

$$
2 I(b)=(1+b)^2 e^{ -b-\frac{1}{1+b}}-e^{-1}+\int\limits_0^bx^2e^{ -x-\frac{1}{1+x}}
$$

For $b \to 0$, the integral on the right is $O(b^3)$ and we have

$$
I(b)>>\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^bx^2e^{ -x-\frac{1}{1+x}}  \ \ , \ \ b \to 0
$$

Therefore

$$
I(b) \sim \frac{1}{2} \left( (1+b)^2 e^{ -b-\frac{1}{1+b}}-e^{-1} \right) \ \ , \ \ b \to 0
$$

Simplifying, I find the leading order term

$$
I(b) \sim \frac{b}{e} \ \ , \ \ b \to 0
$$

In principle, repeated integration by parts could produce the asymptotic series. Here is a plot of the first term versus the numerical integration for small $b$:

[image]

*For large $X$*

I'll use the substitution in the comments: $t=x+1$ to write

$$
e^{-2} \int\limits_0^X \ dx \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{1+x} \right) =\int\limits_1^a dt \ \exp(-t-t^{-1})
$$

And we're investigating $a \to \infty$. Let $f(t)=\exp(-t-t^{-1})$, rewrite the integral

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty dt \ f(t) = \int\limits_0^1 dt \ f(t) + \int\limits_1^a dt \ f(t) + \int\limits_a^\infty dt \ f(t)
$$

The integral on the left is exactly $2K_1(2)$, where $K$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind. The first integral on the right is also constant, independent of $a$. We are left with the simpler problem of studying

$$
I(a)=\int\limits_a^\infty dt \ e^{-t-t^{-1}}
$$

For large $a$. Integrate by parts

$$
I(a)=\int\limits_a^\infty dt \ e^{-t^{-1}} \frac{d}{dt} \left[ -e^{-t} \right]
$$

$$
I(a)=-e^{-t-t^{-1}} \Big\vert_a^\infty + \int\limits_a^\infty dt \ \frac{1}{t^2} e^{-t-t^{-1}}
$$

The integral on the right differs from $I(a)$ by a factor of $1/t^2$, thus we have

$$
I(a)>> \int\limits_a^\infty dt \ \frac{1}{t^2} e^{-t-t^{-1}} \ \ , \ \ a \to \infty 
$$

Which leads to

$$
I(a) \sim e^{-a} \ \ , \ \ a \to \infty 
$$

Finally,

$$
\int\limits_1^a dt \ \exp(-t-t^{-1}) \sim 2K_1(2) - C - e^{-a} \ \ , \ \ a \to \infty
$$

Where $C=\int_0^1 dt \ f(t)$, and can be found numerically to be about $0.072$; probably there is a nice way to estimate it, but I don't see it right now. Here is a plot of the approximation versus the exact numerical integral:

[image]

EDIT: In terms of the [incomplete Bessel functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042707002014), defined as

$$
K_\nu(x,y)=\int\limits_1^\infty dt \ t^{-\nu-1} \exp(-xt -y/t)
$$

We have for $I(a)$, by changing variables $u = t/a$

$$
I(a)=a \int\limits_1^\infty du \  e^{-au-a^{-1} u^{-1}} = a K_{-1}(a,a^{-1})
$$

And for $C$, by changing variables $u= 1/t$

$$
C= \int\limits_1^\infty du \ u^{-2} e^{-u- u^{-1}} =  K_{1}(1,1)
$$

Thus your original integral, with $a=X+1$ may be written

$$
\int\limits_0^X \ dx \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{1+x} \right) = e^2 \left[ 2K_1(2) - K_{1}(1,1) - a K_{-1}(a,a^{-1}) \right] 
$$