# Is there an antiderivative for $e^{-\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

I was playing around with some integrals I made up myself and was trying to find a closed-form for

> $$
> \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)} \ dx, \qquad t < \infty
> $$

I'm aware that if we let $t \to \infty$ then a solution can be obtained in terms of a modified Bessel function, but I couldn't seem to get a result for the finite-limit version.
By plugging the integral into WolframAlpha it replies that the integral above doesn't have an elementary solution. However, I would like to find *any* possible closed form, even if it's in terms of special functions (which will very likely be necessary if such a closed-form exists).

I tried doing integration by parts, which resulted in the identity
$$
\int_{0}^{t} e^{-\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)} \ dx = - e^{-\left( t + \frac{1}{t}\right)}  +\int_{\frac{1}{t}}^{\infty} e^{-\left( u + \frac{1}{u}\right)} \ du
$$
which makes the problem equivalent to finding a solution to $\int_{\tau}^{\infty} e^{-\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)} \ dx$, but I again didn't see how this could help much.

---

Does anyone know any way to get a closed-form for said integral? Or alternatively, is there a way to prove that  $F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)} \ dx$ is "independent" of other special functions, and as such, would need to be defined as its own "new kind" of special function?

Comment: See the second part of [the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021830/indefinite-integral-of-e-frac-x21x/4022155#4022155). What do you mean 'independent' of other special functions? Many special functions are complete, so your $F(t)$ could be expanded in their basis.

Comment: We have $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x+1/x)}dx=2 K_1(2)$, where $K$ is modified Bessel function.